# Metodo .ehlo() y .helo() de smtplib en python3

Tags: python-3.x

Alguien me podria explicar para que son estos metodos?

Casi siempre veo el .ehlo() antes y despues, ( o solo antes ) del .starttls(),  para que sirve el ehlo().

Y hay otro muy parecido llamado .helo()

Alguien sabe para que sirven?

Ya vi la documentacion, pero no me ha quedado del todo claro.

muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, no añadas lo de "espero pronta respuesta", pues parece que estés metiendo prisa.

Comment: Gracias, se me fue la mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El protocolo SMTP original no preveía la posibilidad de canales cifrados, y otros comandos que se añadieron después, como por ejemplo la posibilidad de que exigir al cliente que se autentique mediante nombre de usuario y contraseña.

En el SMTP original, el primer comando que el cliente debía enviar, tras establecer la conexión, era el comando HELO. Esto es lo que hace el método `.helo()`, enviar ese comando mediante el protocolo apropiado. El servidor, si no hay problemas, debería responder con un código que indica que es correcto y un mensaje de bienvenida. A partir de ese punto comenzaría el protocolo para transmitir el mensaje. Este protocolo como he dicho va sin cifrar, por lo que no es seguro.

Posteriormente SMTP se ampliaría para incluir el comando STARTTLS y otros de autenticación. Pero durante un tiempo (y aún hoy) convivieron servidores que seguían el estándar antiguo, junto con otros que seguían el nuevo. Para permitir la compatibilidad hacia atrás, el nuevo estándar añadió el comando EHLO como mensaje de bienvenida.

Si el servidor es moderno, cuando recibe el comando EHLO responderá con la lista de comandos nuevos que soporta (por ejemplo STARTTLS estará entre ellos, que sirve para pasar la conexión a un canal cifrado). Si en cambio es un servidor antiguo que no soporta los nuevos comandos, no entenderá EHLO y responderá con un código de error. Esto permite saber al cliente qué versión del protocolo soporta el servidor.

Por otro lado, una vez se ha ejecutando el comando STARTTLS y se está ya en modo seguro, el cliente necesitará enviar de nuevo EHLO para recibir otra vez la lista de comandos permitidos, pues esa lista puede variar con respecto a la que se recibió la primera vez, ya que al estar ahora el canal cifrado, el servidor soportará métodos de autenticación adicionales (que no soportaría en un canal sin cifrar).

Comment: Entonces por este motivo, al usar starttls, el metodo ehlo() debe ir antes y despues de su uso, verdad?

Comment: Sí, tiene que ir antes para que el servidor entienda que eres un cliente "moderno" y te ofrezca la posibilidad de hacer STARTTLS. Y tiene que ir otra vez después para que el cliente descubra qué métodos de autenticación soporta ese servidor.